# How do I slice a sequence to get the last item?

Tags: python

I am practicing slicing, and I want to run a program that prints a name backwards.

Mainly, I want to know how to access the last item in the sequence.

I wrote the following:

```
name = raw_input("Enter Your Name: ")
backname = ???

print backname
```

Is this a sound approach? Obviously, the `???` is not a part of my syntax, just asking what should go there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [good primer for python slice notation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/good-primer-for-python-slice-notation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access the last item in a sequence, use:

```
print name[-1]
```

This is the same as:

```
print name[len(name) - 1]
```

Reversing a sequence has a common idiom in Python:

```
backname = name[::-1]
```

The [Good primer for Python slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/good-primer-for-python-slice-notation) question has more complete information.

Answer (score 1):

```
backname[-1] #the last item in the sequence

 #To reverse backname (the long way):
aList = [c for c in backname]  #will give you ['1', '2', ..., 'n']
aList.reverse()                #aList will be ['n', ..., '2', '1] 
backname = "".join(aList)      #backname reversed

 #To reverse backname, as other answers replied:
 backname[::-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You want `name[::-1]`.  The -1 is the "step" of the slice-- if you wanted every other letter, for example, you would use `name[::2]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use negative indices to access items counting from the end of a list, so `name[-1]` will give you the last character. However, the third slice argument is a step, which can also be negative, so this will give you the whole string in reverse:

```
name[::-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

With slice syntax, you would use:

```
backname = name[::-1]
```

The two colons show that the first two parameters to the slice are left at their defaults, so start at the beginning, process to the end, but step backwards (the -1).

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to read the docs:
http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-buffer-xrange

There's a method to reverse the string for you, if you want. For the specific question you asked, to access the last item of a sequence you use "seq[-1]".

Answer (score 0):

It does look sound. And your second line should be

```
backname = name[::-1]
```